# Missing tunisian crochet tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I just noticed there is no tunisian crochet tag, which would be applicable to these two questions:

[How to prevent Tunisian crochet from curling?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/4144/how-to-prevent-tunisian-crochet-from-curling)

[What's the difference between crochet, knitting, and tunisian crochet?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/87/whats-the-difference-between-crochet-knitting-and-tunisian-crochet)

Sadly I do not have the prerequisite reputation to create it :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done! [tunisian-crochet](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tunisian-crochet) :)